# Div with background image inside div doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, background

I have a div with background image put inside another div, instead of fit width parent div, it fit full screen. Please take a look my code to know clearly, sorry for bad english.

http://codepen.io/thehung1724/full/jEEgQq/

**HTML**

```
<div id="video-section" class="dark-section">
  <div class="home"></div>
    <div class="fullscreen-img" style="background-image: url(http://upanh.biz/images/2014/11/23/bg1.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#video-section{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1230px;
  height: 500px;
}

.dark-section{
  background-color: black;
}

.home{
    display: table;
    height: 500px;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.fullscreen-img {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: You mean why is the `.fullscreen-img` div fitting the full screen? :)

Comment: Yes, how do I fix it? :)

Comment: The reason why it is full screen is because of position: fixed.  This makes it so the div positioning and dimensions are calculated relative to the viewport, not its parent.  What effect are you going for?

Answer (score 0):

The `.home` div needs to be absolutely positioned in order not to "push" the background div downwards. The background div shouldn't have the `fullscreen-img` class, since most of those rules should be removed. It only needs `height: 100%` because divs have `width: 100%` by default since they're block elements. Of course, move the inline styles into a class or ID rules, I left them there just to show you.

That's all you need basically:

- remove the `.fullscreen-img` class from the background div
- set its height to 100% instead
- make the `.home` div absolutely positioned

---

See it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azzexY

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

#video-section{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1230px;
  height: 500px;
}

.dark-section{
  background-color: black;
}

.home{
    display: table;
    height: 500px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="video-section" class="dark-section">
  <div class="home"></div>
 <div class="" style="height: 100%; background-image: url(http://upanh.biz/images/2014/11/23/bg1.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

---

UPDATE

Fixes/changes for your website for the problematic element (`<div style="background-image: url('images/bg2.jpg');" class="fullscreen-img img-after"></div>`):

- left: initial;
- width: 1230px;

Comment: I'm using mb.YTPlayer plug-in to create video background. The effect I want to try like top video here: http://onlinesneaker.net/temp/magnum/index.html. But their site layout is fullscreen while my site layout is boxed. I don't know how to express my opinion, but I can send you my zip code to check.

Comment: Hmm, it looks pretty messed up, I'm not even sure which part to look at.

Comment: Sorry, the part is "last friday party", its background fitting full-screen.

Comment: There, I added the two modifications you need to apply to the problematic element.

Comment: Thank you, but I have another issue that when scroll down, the image will scroll down too. How do I fix it?

Comment: You're welcome. That issue is unrelated to the fix I gave you btw. To fix it, just add a background to the map and footer elements.

Comment: Yes I know it but I just want to use fixed height, only 500px or more. This is important project for me, hope you help me out.